# Uploading image in server failed CAKEPHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, bluehost

I need help on this one. I have build a web aplication in cakephp. on localhost eveything works just fine. images gets uploaded, inserted, deleted correctly. The moment I uploaded it on server it shows error!

**Notice (8):** Undefined index: Slider [APP/Model/Slider.php, line 245]

**Notice (8):** Undefined index: Slider [APP/Model/Slider.php, line 247]

**Warning (2):** unlink(/home8/ceraunia/public_html/afs/cesi/admin/app/webroot/img/uploads/slider/images/) [function.unlink]: Is a directory [APP/Model/Slider.php, line 248]

i dont know what to do, or where the problem is. As i mentioned in localhost everything works perfect. The host server i use is blueHost.

Any help would be very appruciated..

**EDIT:**

Thi is the code that is causing the problem:

```
 public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    $dir = 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'slider' . DS . 'images' . DS; /*<=== DO NOT EDIT*/
 // then after deletation of the row we check if the file exist, if so we delete it. 
    if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path']) && file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $dir .  $this->image['Slider']['pic_path'])){
        $img = WWW_ROOT . $dir . $this->image['Slider']['pic_path'];
        unlink($img);
        return true;                
   } else { $this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path'] = $this->image['Slider']['pic_path']; }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: may be useful to see the line 245 and 247 of the model Slider ? Also, some specifications of the server (php version for example) compared to your localhost. You're not giving us much info to work with.

Comment: I added the extra lines of code that you asked!... i dont know what am i missing here do you have any idea @Nunser ?

Comment: For what I can see, without knowing what `$this->image` has, that array simply doesn't have the index. Now, why doesn't it have it? I don't know, maybe show how you save that data in the first place? And please add the php and mysql version of your localhost and server

Answer (score 1):

How about simply reading the messages?

> /home8/ceraunia/public_html/afs/cesi/admin/app/webroot/img/uploads/slider/images/)
>   [function.unlink]: **Is a directory**

You're trying to delete a directory with [unlink()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php). I guess, since [you're not showing the stacktrace](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/5c/5c4dd5ff503189844c2539bb4299e274ed3912db2407c622bf34f28e59b98dbf.jpg), that the other two notices coming from the missing file name.

The very basics of debugging: Go to the lines the notices tell you and debug the variables there and see why the index is undefined. You can figure that out by following the path of the code which the stacktrace already tells you.

Yet another guess: You're using windows and the server is a *nix box and you're not using the DS constant for directory separators?

Comment: It's not a directory, its an image within a directory. And the point is the error happens when i try to add a new record. But when i deactivate error reporting. the image does upload succesdully. as it supposed to.

Comment: It is a directory. Or do you think the parser is lying to you? Well, if you think so create a bug report on php.net and tell them unlink() is not working right... I explained as well why it is likely a directory in my answer. Disabling errors is no solution in no case, just horrible bad practice. Start learning how to debug properly.